# JSOUP parsing for multiple rows

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse information from a particular website using JSOUP.
So far I can parse and display a single row, as the website has a lot of html and I am quite new to this I was wondering is there a way to parse all table rows on the page containing the word "fixturerow".

Here is my parser code:

```
 Document doc =Jsoup.connect("http://www.irishrugby.ie/club/ulsterbankleagueandcup/fixtures.php").get();
  Elements kelime = doc.select("tr#fixturerow0");
    for(Element sectd:kelime){
        Elements tds = sectd.select("td"); 

              String result = tds.get(0).text();
               String result1 = tds.get(1).text();
               String result2 = tds.get(2).text();
               String result3 = tds.get(3).text();
               String result4 = tds.get(4).text();
               String result5 = tds.get(5).text();
               String result6 = tds.get(6).text();
               String result7 = tds.get(7).text();


               System.out.println("Date: " + result);
               System.out.println("Time: " + result1);
               System.out.println("League: " + result2);
               System.out.println("Home Team: " + result3);
               System.out.println("Score: " + result4);
               System.out.println("Away Team: " + result5);
               System.out.println("Venue: " + result6);
               System.out.println("Ref: " + result7);

    }`
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So if I am understanding it right, you are able to extract row using id, but now you want to get all rows which contains a word?

Comment: Exactly, although the issue has been resolved below. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `^=` (starts-with) selector:

```
Elements kelime = doc.select("tr[id^=fixturerow]");
```

This will return all elements with an id that starts with `fixturerow`.

Comment: Slight correction, I think the above selector should read: `tr[id^=fixturerow]`

Comment: @glytching Yes, typo. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck if you use a selector that looks for id's that **start-with** the text of interest. So try changing

```
Elements kelime = doc.select("tr#fixturerow0");
```

to

```
Elements kelime = doc.select("tr[id^=fixturerow]");
```

Where `^=` means that the text of interest starts with the text that follows.

Comment: You're welcome. I was a few minutes too slow. 1+ to backslash